# Utilizing Blue prints most effectively in Flask?

Tags: flask

I'm want to try remaking my the software I build at work which is a java/jython/python 2.5 personal hellscape of my everyday existence to a single page app (if possible) using Flask.

I'm pretty familiar with flask in terms of routing, posting forms to databases and reading from databases to template a page.  But so far every time I've made a blueprint it seems to have been mostly done for separation of concern concerns, I've never reused a blueprint with a different suffix, but now I think it might appropriate for this context.

I have multiple business entities that all just have to follow a CRUD cycle.  Invoices, sales orders, quotes, etc.  Each of these should have exactly four routes

`<entity name>/create` would have a GET to return the appropriate HTML web page, and a POST that would send the form fields to the appropriate columns of the appropriate database table.

`<entity name>/read/<id>` would only have a GET to return the HTML page with the entity form already filled out with info from the database.

`<entity name>/update/<id>` would only have a POST, to update the page served in the read route if the action is take.

`<entity name>/delete/<id>` would only have a POST route.

With these 4 routes being the only ones required for every entity, would it be 1) recommended to use one general blue print for all these entities? If so, 2) how would I set up database table names/the folder structure to best utilize the generic blueprint?

It's worth noting too that some of the entities need not only to update the database table that shares their name, but also some multi-key tables, while others do not.  I know this is somewhat a generic question so I tried adding detail, I can add further detail where requested.

Comment: _to a single page app (if possible) using Flask_. Does this mean you're wanting to build an API, or the full app in Flask?

Comment: A full application.  It's just an app to do CRUD operations on a database, and live update tables without refreshing if possible.  That's the extent of my current application so if I could copy that behavior (which my boss loves) I think I could sell him on moving to making this a website instead.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to set up for Blueprints:

Put all python files for routes, forms, background utils, and a templates folder for applicable html templates into separate folders for each of the CRUD sections you mention above.

For each folder (e.g. 'folder_name'), its **init**.py contains:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_breadcrumbs import default_breadcrumb_root

bp = Blueprint('folder_name', __name__, template_folder='templates')
default_breadcrumb_root(bp, '.')

from app.folder_name import routes
```

The various routes.py should contain routings such as:

```
@bp.route('/read', methods=['GET'], strict_slashes=False)
@register_breadcrumb(bp, '.this.that', 'My Breadcrumb')
```

One folder up at 'app', the create_app function in '**init**.py' should contain:

```
from app.folder_name import bp as one_bp
app.register_blueprint(one_bp, url_prefix='/<entity_name>')
# etc, for each app/<folder>
```

I've included Breadcrumbs into this app structure. Menu can be similarly included.